# Stream from netcat to front-end

Tags: node.js, linux, video, stream, video-streaming

I am trying to get this configuration for video transmission:

```
Raspberry Pi => Node.js server => Browsers
```

The main advantage is that there can be several browsers and the Raspberry Pi doesn't get overloaded. Now, I got this far working for video streaming:

```
Raspberry Pi => Linux laptop
```

With those commands:

```
// [first] Computer: listen to video and play it with mplayer
nc -l 2222 | mplayer -fps 200 -demuxer h264es -

// [second] Raspberry Pi (emit video to the IP)
raspivid -t 0 -w 300 -h 300 -hf -fps 20 -o - | nc 192.168.1.44 2222
```

I am trying first to replace the computer side. I got this code so far:

```js
const NetcatServer = require('netcat/server');
const nc = new NetcatServer();
const stream = nc.port(2222).k().listen();
stream.pipe(process.stdout);  // ~ correct
```

However, if I try to listen to the `stream` with a `data` event like this:

```js
let i = 0;
stream.on('data', () => {
  i++;
  console.log(i);
});
```

With this `on('data', ...)` the stream works for 20-25 events and then stops (something that didn't happen with stdout). So my questions:

- How to put this stream from the back-end to the front-end? (taking into account that it *"ends"*.

Note: I check the `end`, `error`, `finish` and `destroy` event but none are triggered while streaming. It just sort of stops.

Comment: did you take a look at setting maxListeners on a stream?                                           whenever you do `stream.pipe(process.stdout)`, it automatically ends the stream, to avoid this just listen for the end event on the stream, but before that you have to pass a second argument to `stream.pipe` which is `stream.pipe(process.stdout, {end: false})` . After that, you should listen for the end event